# Output of Select query to be used as input for the other Query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$id=mysql_query("Select customerId from LoginInfo where username='$un'");
$res4=mysql_query("SELECT d.title, dateRented, totalRent
FROM CustomerDvdRental c, DvdInventory d
WHERE c.customerId = '$ID[0]' && d.dvdId = c.dvdId");
```

how can i use `$id` as input for my other select Query please help i tried everything i guess it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch a row from the query object because mysql_query only returns a resource and this cannot be accessed like an array. So on line two include the code:

```
$id = mysql_fetch_array($id);
```

This should solve your problem.

But in the end I would clear up the code to be more concise. This will make your code more maintainable. e.g.

```
$resource=mysql_query("Select customerId from LoginInfo where username='$un'");
$loginInfo = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
$res4=mysql_query("SELECT d.title, dateRented, totalRent
FROM CustomerDvdRental c, DvdInventory d
WHERE c.customerId = ".$loginInfo[0]." && d.dvdId = c.dvdId");
```

References: This will show you some examples and tell you what the function does: https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Notes: i think this approach is no good. You are not checking the input at all and you are not even escaping sql characters. This opens up your application to sql injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
To avoid this I would probably rewrite the whole entire code base to use mysqli which auto escapes quotes and such and then check your input to a whitelist.

Comment: Great [first] answer! You might also want to suggest PDO along with mysqli.

Comment: its working.... i am new to php and web designing as well so starting with basic things but yes  i will definately try to learn and try to implement them. really appreciate you help thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

Try JOIN

SELECT d.title,.. FROM DvdInventory d
JOIN CustomerDvdRental c
ON d.dvdId = c.dvdId
JOIN LoginInfo l
ON c.customerId = l.customerId AND l.username='$un'

Answer (score 0):

Try `$id[0]` in lower case. Php is case sensitive.

Edit : add this like previous reply:

```
$id = mysql_fetch_array($id);
```

Be carefull to the case.